# Hibernate Transactional Commits

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I am working in a spring boot app, and I have some methods that go through a list and perform multiple commits to the database through hibernate.

For example, I receive an object from the front end that the user has modified, and that object has many samples associated to it, and each sample has many tests associated to it.

In this scenario, i need to generate a copy of the object, its samples, and the tests and save them.

The issue im having is if somewhere in the middle an exception happens, hibernate only rolls back the most recent commit action. But i need to roll back everything from the start.

I am still new to using hibernate and spring, so my question is if you have a method that is performing multiple repository.save() calls (because you are saving across multiple tables) and something goes wrong, how can you roll back all the save() actions you have performed during this transaction?

Is there an annotation i can put on my function that does this for me?

Comment: What have you tried so far (code wise)?

Comment: I have not tried anything as of yet. I was under the assumption that Hibernate would roll things back for me, but this is only true if it is a single .save(), or bulk save.   As soon as you make another .save() call it will not roll back the first one if something goes wrong during the second.  I had considered keeping track of the PK's that are being generated and then in the catch() removing them, but there has to be a better way to let Spring/Hibernate rollback everything for me, even when there are multiple commit actions.

Comment: You could try making a temporary instance of the repository (or perhaps save all data individually, although that would probably be insane) the beginning of the method, and if you get an error, reset the main repository instance to the saved temporary one. That’s really all I can think if ATM

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the annotation bellow on method from service, should help you:

```
@Transactional(rollbackFor = Exception.class)
```

You must throw an exception somewhere in service method and the Spring will roll back the transaction if a thrown error is occurred.

Comment: Yes, thank you. I found this after doing some digging through documentation. I put `@Transactional("oracleTransactionManager")` on my Service method that decides whether it needs to call the Create, Update or Delete methods. This allows the single @Transactional instance to propagate through all the other methods until everything is complete. Works perfectly.